# Not able to sculpt details

Tags: sculpting, subdivision-surface

I recently started blender and I made the basic shape of my model in edit mode and I want to start sculpting. I'm trying to sculpt details like folds in the skin, but I'm not able to add really small details like in this youtube video.
[image]

I looked for some videos on sculpting details but none of them really helped me. I'm assuming I'm not able to add these details because I don't have enough vertices but I'm unable to add a subdivision modifier because I was impatient and started sculpting the flank with the dyntopo on and a bunch of vertices were added and the app crashes when I try to add one.
[image]

I'm using shade smooth to make it look smooth. I'm not sure how I should proceed and I need advice.

Thanks, sorry for my run on sentances.

Comment: I'm not a regular user of the sculpt tool, but it isn't wise to use dyntopo before subdivision surface, simply because the amount of faces increases by about 4 times (around that number), which can make blender crash. Try zooming in more, if you use the 5 on the numpad you can go closer. That way you should be able to add more detail

Comment: Welcome to BSE. A tip from me is to save often and backup (save as) often.  My avatar is my first model from circa 2007, no idea what I was doing: modifiers were applied willy nilly etc etc, till it was a zillion vertex mesh network of triangles very similar to flanks in image above. Good to learn from experience (sometimes aka mistakes)... handy to be able to roll back.